# Updating multiple rows using list of Ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update multiple rows in the table on the basis of Ids. In the stored procedure, I'm creating a varchar variable that holds the Ids list.

Now, in the table I have entries with Ids 1, 2. The varchar variable has value `1,2`; so I'm expecting no row to be updated with following query.

```
UPDATE mytbl
SET flag = 1
WHERE Id IN (IdList); -- Here IdList has value '1,2'
```

But here row with Id as `2` is getting updated. Select query also returns the same row. 
I tried concatenating `IdList` as `"'1','2'"`, then it retuens both the rows (with Ids 1 and 2).
The data type of `Id` is `int`. Is there proper way to maintain integer list?

Comment: The `IdList` value must be `'1','2'` not `'1,2'`

Comment: In the second approach I did that, but it returned both the rows.

Comment: where do you actually get the idlist from? Is it data you fetch from your database, or do you get it from "outside"?

Comment: @Olli, from the database.

Comment: @benjamin54 i know its not of any use, but you should probably think about a table that holds this kind of information to be easily retrieved instead of comma separated lists..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE mytbl
SET flag = 1
WHERE @IdList LIKE CONCAT('%,',Id,',%');
```

Note that your varchar list `@IdList` must start and end with comma (e.g. `,1,2,20,30,`).

Answer (score 13):

just use the ids as integers like so:

```
UPDATE mytbl
SET flag = 1
WHERE id in (1,2,3,....)
```

Comment: I'm creating a list (varchar) with Ids to update. That is not working. How my list should look like?

Comment: as far as i remember there is no split function available in MySQL, so you would really have to provide that list from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically generate subquery where the list in not VARCHAR but part of text of query. I.e. implement this in higher level language (perl/python/php).

Comment: That smells a bit like SQL-injection, since the IN term will only work if the varchar variable is pasted in as a string: you can't bind it in as variable.

Comment: It will be injection if ID list comes from outside source (web interface/service). When it is generated internally in software, there is no risk of injection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I need to decide those Ids in procedure itself.

Comment: Then you can use Cursor to process the VARCHAR and extract each ID. Store it in temporary table and then run your query joinet to temp table. Use LOCATE and SUBSTRING in the cursor loop to split the id-s.

Comment: Thanks, I know temp table approach will work, but I thought there might be some simple alternative available. So I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

You Should try Left join as you are getting a @table type parameter of IDs this will give fast and more reliable result :)

```
UPDATE 
    mytbl
SET
    flag = 1
FROM
    @IdList idL
    LEFT JOIN mytbl mTbl ON mTbl.ID = idL.Table_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works, here you don't need to have comma at the start and the end of defined variable.

```
SET @IdList = "1,2";

UPDATE mytbl
SET flag = 1
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(Id, @IdList);
```